# When clicking `Report bug` during Kiwi TCMS TestExecution no URL for editing is opened

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I [configured Redmine as external bug tracker](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers)

- `Tracker type`: [tcms.issuetracker.types.Redmine](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.Redmine)
- `Base URL` and `API URL` both point to the base URL of our Redmine instance. I am not sure what to set in `API URL` though. If I leave `API URL` blank this issue stays the same.
- `API username` and `Api password` are apparently correct

## Steps to reproduce

1. During TestExecution click `Report bug`

## Expected result

According to [report_issue_from_testexecution(execution, user)](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#tcms.issuetracker.types.Redmine.report_issue_from_testexecution):

> When marking TestExecution results inside a Test Run there is a Report link. When the Report link is clicked this method is called to help the user report an issue in the IT.
>
> This is implemented by constructing an URL string which will pre-fill bug details like steps to reproduce, product, version, etc from the test case. Then we open this URL into another browser window!

## Actual result

An issue is created in Redmine but no URL for editing is opened in another browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.html#module-tcms.issuetracker, emphasis mine

> 1-click bug report - by clicking a UI element inside TestExecution
> Kiwi TCMS will try to automatically report a new bug in the selected
> bug tracker. **If this fails will fall back to opening a new browser
> window to manually enter the required information.** Fields will be
> pre-filled with correct information when possible.

The functionality you are looking for is a fallback functionality. In your case Kiwi TCMS is able to communicate with Redmine without any errors and is able to create the bug report in Redmine without errors. Hence the user isn't provided an opportunity to edit the initial report manually.